# issue with changing animation of body in Box2D game

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

im stuck in weird problem, im making one box2d game in which my character has different animation for walking, jumping and standing. i'v problem in switching these. here is my code..

controlLayer.m

```
-(id)init{    
    self=[super init];    
    screenSize=[[CCDirector sharedDirector]winSize];    
    if(self!=nil){        
        [self initJoystickAndButtons];
        [self scheduleUpdate];        
return self;
    }
}



-(void)applyJoystick:(SneakyJoystick *)aJoystick forTimeDelta:(float)deltaTime
{          
        if(aJoystick.velocity.x > 0.0f)  {            
            [level1 walkBunny:(ccTime)aJoystick.velocity.x];         
        }            
    if(aJoystick.velocity.y > 0.0f) {                            
            b2Vec2 force;
            force.Set(0.0f, 150.0f);
            level1.bunnyBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(force, level1.bunnyBody->GetWorldCenter());                
            [level1 jumpBunny];                    
        }

   if(aJoystick.velocity.x == 0.0f) {
        [level1 standBunny];
       }          
    }    
}
```

as u can see, i have called three different state of my character which defines it animation here, now here are those methods...applyJoystick is called from my update method.

level1Layer.m

```
-(void)walkBunny:(ccTime)duration{        
    NSLog(@"IN WALK BUNNY");
    [animatingCyclist stopAllActions];        
    cyclistAnim = [CCAnimation animation];          
    [cyclistAnim addFrameWithFilename:@"walking-step-2.png"];         
    [cyclistAnim addFrameWithFilename:@"walking-step-3.png"]; 
    [cyclistAnim addFrameWithFilename:@"walking-step-4.png"];
    [cyclistAnim addFrameWithFilename:@"walking-step-5.png"];
    [cyclistAnim addFrameWithFilename:@"walking-step-6.png"];
    [cyclistAnim addFrameWithFilename:@"walking-step-7.png"];
    [cyclistAnim addFrameWithFilename:@"walking-step-8.png"];
    [cyclistAnim addFrameWithFilename:@"walking-step-9.png"];        
    cyclistAnimationAction = [CCAnimate actionWithDuration:(ccTime)duration                                                 animation:cyclistAnim restoreOriginalFrame:YES];        
    id repeatcyclistAnimation = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:cyclistAnimationAction];       
    [animatingCyclist runAction:repeatcyclistAnimation];    

}

-(void)jumpBunny{    
    NSLog(@"IN JUMP BUNNY");
    [animatingCyclist stopAllActions];        
    cyclistAnim = [CCAnimation animation];          
    [cyclistAnim addFrameWithFilename:@"jumping-step-1.png"];
    [cyclistAnim addFrameWithFilename:@"jumping-step-2.png"];        
    [cyclistAnim addFrameWithFilename:@"jumping-step-3.png"]; 
    [cyclistAnim addFrameWithFilename:@"jumping-step-4.png"];
    [cyclistAnim addFrameWithFilename:@"jumping-step-5.png"];
    [cyclistAnim addFrameWithFilename:@"jumping-step-6.png"];
    [cyclistAnim addFrameWithFilename:@"jumping-step-7.png"];         
    cyclistAnimationAction = [CCAnimate actionWithDuration:5.5f                                                  animation:cyclistAnim restoreOriginalFrame:YES];       
    [animatingCyclist runAction:cyclistAnimationAction];        

}
```

and same for standBunny...

issue with this is, my these methods are being called repeatedly on standing and walking that before one iteration of animation it is called again, so my animation get not completed and it ll show first image of animation everytime. hope you all get my problem! :(

Answer (score 0):

You're stopping the animation an create it all over again every frame. For instance:

```
 if(aJoystick.velocity.x > 0.0f)  {            
            [level1 walkBunny:(ccTime)aJoystick.velocity.x];         
        }
```

Read this as: "as long as horizontal velocity is greater than 0, stop and restart the walk bunny animation".

You need to check if the velocity has changed state from <= 0.0f to > 0.0f and only then call the walkbunny method once.

Comment: but once i get velocity >0.0f, my condition will be true and walkbunny will be called continuously, how can i set it to be called with sync of my animation!?